# Enviar imagem entre páginas javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma imagem que foi upada pelo usuário e preciso envia-la pra outra página pra exibir na tela antes de enviar para o banco de dados.

Alguma sugestão de como fazer isso?

Comment: Joga a imagem para um pasta e recupera da outra página

Comment: Se foi upada foi upada para uma pasta no seu servidor correto? Dai tem várias formas de mostrar na outra página. Se acessar a outra página através de link envie o nome no link e na outra pagina recupere ele e coloque no src da imagem. Se não for assim, guarde esse nome em cookie ou sessionStorage ou localStorage e recupere ele na outra página

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão, você pode salvar essa imagem (stream) em um dos WebStores, assim você terá acesso rápido e fácil.

Pode usar o localStorage: (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

para salvar o stream da imagem:

```
localStorage.setItem('NAME','IMG_STREAM');
```

para pegar o stream:

```
localStorage.getItem('NAME');
```

Você pode acompanhar os valores dos storages na guia 'Application' na ferramenta de desenvolvimento do navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]